# dev c++ outdated libs and includes

Tags: c++, static-libraries, dev-c++

Includes and libs in latest MinGW version of dev c++ are outdated. For Example there is no functions like `QueryFullProcessImageName` or `GetProcessImageFileName`. Is it possible to simple update them?

Comment: I'm talking about both versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried pointing the compiler to the needed libraries? On TDM-GCC 4.6.1 included with Dev-C++ 5.3, this compiles fine:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>

int main() {
    LPSTR dummy;
    GetProcessImageFileName(NULL,dummy,0);
    return 0;
}
```

All that is needed to get it to link too is the library. As with all nonstandard libraries, you need to point the compiler to the proper libraries yourself. This time, look for this file which is always provided with the bundled compilers:

```
Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpsapi.a (for MinGW64)
or
Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib32/libpsapi.a (for MinGW64, 32bit mode)
or
Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib/libpsapi.a (for vanilla MinGW)
```

This pointing can be done for project via Project >> Project Options >> Parameters >> Add Library or Object via a GUI. Point the file dialog to the above file. Hit OK. Alternatively, send the path of the .a file directly to gcc using Tools >> Compiler Options >> Custom Compiler Command (top edit field).

Then recompile. Done. Please don't blindly blame the compiler/IDE for this.

Answer (score -1):

There is a new version of Dev-C++ developed separately, and if you really want to stick to this pseudo-IDE, you should download it; it should have newer toolset.

*Please* consider switching to anything else.

Comment: Are you talking about Dev-C++ 5.3.0.4? It's also outdated.

Comment: @CharlieHopperson Did you think about switching to a good IDE instead?

Comment: Code::Block needs the same compilator... Visual Studio can't be.

Comment: I can not use M$ compiler. If it possible, it must be an updated GNU GCC compiler. I've downloaded newest pack but it seems not having any includes or libs

Comment: @CharlieHopperson "I can't use this compiler" why?

Comment: Cause it needs an extra software to download. I've recently made a win32 app, but on second machine (with win 7) I had to download C++ runtime or something like that. This app must be universal to use on every windows between XP and 8.

Comment: Why don't you link to runtime statically or supply redists with your app?

Comment: So how do you imagine Dev C++ compiles the code so that it doesn't have to supply it?

Comment: @CharlieHopperson: that separately developed Dev-C++ currently ships with MinGW 4.7.2 or TDM-GCC 4.6.1/4.7.1 x64. These compilers are about as new as GCC can get on Windows.